# What is best ways to associate nested objects in ES6?

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var obj = {
  value: "abc",
  sample: "test1,test2,test3",
  nestedObj: {
    code:test1;
    display:"tes"
  },
  nestedOb2: {
    code:test2;
    display:"tes"
  }
};
```

The output I want is,

```
var obj = {
  value:"abc",
  sample:[{
      code:test1,
      display: "tes"
    },{
      test2,
      display: "tes"
   }
```

I want the best and efficient way to do this ES6,any solutions will help me a lot

Comment: the question is not quite clear. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: `{test2,display:` That is invalid syntax.

Comment: You have critical syntax error in `JavaScript` object, I edited them for you, but your answer is not clear, what's your stack, how you made this object?

Comment: I have submitted further edits with indentation to illustrate the incompleteness of the objects. Use indentation. Use a linter (ESLINT for example) https://eslint.org/demo/  you can even paste your objects right in.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var obj = {sample: []}; 
 obj.value = "abc";
 obj.sample.push({
      code:'test1',
      display: "tes"
    },{
      code:'test2',
      display: "tes"
   })
console.log(obj)
```

Simple initialize an array inside object and push all object inside an array.will solve the issue.

Comment: I have to split the sample property of first object into array of strings and then match that string with the code of the neatedobj if both are equal then only I have to push, simply I cannot push it , I have achieved it using nested for loops but I was look for efficient solution

Comment: @Divya on which bases you have loop the code...? i don't see the condition where to loop.... :-)

Comment: I have one object which has "sample" property as 'test1,test2,test3',I have to construct a  new object by converting sample to string of array and matching it with the nestedobject code value.